# Which integrals can be solved using Feynman's Technique?

Tags: integration

How to check whether an integral can be easily solved using Feynman's approach. What are the main criteria needed to be taken into account?

Comment: It's sort of a misnomer to refer to it as Feynman's technique.  Most calculus textbooks from the 1800's and early 1900's have a section on the usefulness of differentiating under the integral to evaluate definite integrals. But then it was seemingly forgotten about for a while.

Comment: Here is a [paper](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf) that might answer your question.